# How to retrieve data from Polymorphic Relations with Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new in Laravel. I'm developing a demo with `Polymorphic Relations` follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

I set up 3 tables:

```
--Users
  --id
  --username
--Posts
  --id
  --summary
  --published
--Images
  --id
  --link
  --alt
  --image_id
  --image_type
```

`App\Models\Users`

```
public function scopeWithImages()
{
    return static::with('images')->get();
}

public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Images', 'image');
}
```

`App\Models\Posts`

```
public function scopeWithImages()
{
    return static::with('images')->get();
}

public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Images', 'image');
}
```

`App\Models\Images`

```
public function scopeWithUsers ()
{
    return static::with('users')->get();
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Users', 'image');
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Posts', 'image');
}
```

I got Images collection by calling `Users` and `Posts` model easily.
How I got Users and Posts collection from `Images` model? I got error `Unknown column 'images.images_id'`

Answer (score 4):

your relationship method are wrong it should be like this

`App\Models\Users`

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Images', 'image');
}
```

`App\Models\Posts`

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Images', 'image');
}
```

`App\Models\Images`

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

the method name should be column name before the underscore `image_id == image()`

prefer - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: I still got error `Unknown column 'images.images_id' in 'field list' `

Comment: how did you made call?

Answer (score 1):

first, your idea is incorrect because the relation between images and users and post is one to many polymorphic, in this scenario you just need to write `$user->images` to retrieve images that belong to the user or write`$post->images` to get post images.

// but in your code
you want each user or post have many images that might be for user or post or all together in your senario you `$post = Post::find(1); dd($post->images)` to retrive images of one post

hope this work for you